# react re-render component but not the whole page issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to re-render one component on my webpage in react and I am having troubles. When I click the back button, I want to go to the section which is alphabetically previous to the current one - I break down the sections of my component into letters. So my handleBack function should re-render the component. This is my code below:

```
function handleBack() {
    const currentId = window.location.href.split('/').pop();

    const backId = String.fromCharCode(currentId.charCodeAt() - 1);

    return(

       <Route>

         <Redirect from={'/form/${currentId}'} to={'/form/${backId}'} />

       </Route>);

}
```

It knows that currentID is B and backID is A for example, but it isn't re-rendering the component and showing page A. Why is this happening? How do I fix this? I thought route and redirect would work but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you share complete component code?

Answer (score 0):

First

Change this to....

```
function handleBack() {
    const currentId = window.location.href.split('/').pop();

    const backId = String.fromCharCode(currentId.charCodeAt() - 1);

    return(

       <Route>

         <Redirect from={'/form/${currentId}'} to={'/form/${backId}'} />

       </Route>);

}
```

To...

```
function handleBack() {
    const currentId = this.props.match.params.id; // Use the route params instead of using window.location

    const backId = String.fromCharCode(currentId.charCodeAt() - 1);

    this.props.history.push('/form/${backId}');

}
```

Comment: this doesn't work as it's a function and i am not using any props.. this gives me an error as it can't read props of undefined :(

Comment: You can force refresh to see the issue with the code
`this.forceUpdate() `
You can place this inside a `constructor()`  or `componentDidMount()`